# What way would you choose to create Anonymous Cases

Tags: case, anonymous

We have a need for some cases to be created where it is imperative that the creator of the case is anonymous.

I have 2 ideas:

1. Using the SFDC UI I could put a 'Before Insert' trigger that sets the 'Created By' to be an Anonymous User license
2. I could remove the user from Salesforce, a web page, and load the data in over API as the Anonymous User licence

This would allow us to keep the names of case creators out of the system so that there is no way that the creator may be identified.

Can you think of another way to achieve this?

Edit: An anonymous user: a user license that is used solely for pushing these records into the system. Could be guest or a full license named appropriately.

Comment: CreatedById isn't writeable, if you could create a page and then do it over an API it should be a sys admin user wouldn't it?

Comment: what is an `anonymous user license`? There is a guest user license used for Sites and unauthenticated Community users. Where are these "maskable" cases originating from?

Comment: @EricSSH You can set CreatedDate and CreatedById fields value while uploading the Data into Salesforce Org using API. - That may rule out #1